# What are the general procedures for simplifying a trigonometric expression using Euler's formula?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

What are the general procedures for simplifying a trigonometric expression using Euler's formula? As an example, this is how we can *simplify* the following trigonometric expression:

---

$$\sin{x}\cos{x}$$

$$\sin{x}\cos{x} = \dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i} \times \dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$$

$$ = \dfrac{(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})}{4i}$$
$$ = \dfrac{(e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix})}{4i}$$
$$ = \dfrac{1}{2} \times \dfrac{(e^{i(2x)}-e^{-i(2x)})}{2i}$$
$$ = \dfrac{1}{2} \times \sin(2x)$$

---

However, how would you approach other expressions? What general steps can you take to simplify any trigonometric expression, such as the following:

$$ \tan^{-1}(\dfrac{\cos{x}-\sin{x}}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}})$$
Where $\dfrac{-\pi}{4} < x < \dfrac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Note that since $\sin(2x) = 2\sin x\cos x$, then $\sin x\cos x = \frac{1}{2}\times\sin(2x)$, i.e., it's not $\frac{1}{2}\times\cos(2x)$ as you wrote.

Comment: For this particular identity it's also efficient to write $x = u + \frac\pi4$, expand using angle sum identities, and simplify.

Comment: Did you think that $\sin x$ is equal to $\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2}$? It isn't. You seem to have your formulas mixed up.

Comment: Sorry about the error; it should hopefully be fine now.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the sines and cosines by the $e^{ix}$ expressions, and simplify. That'll make the argument to arctan a lot simpler. In fact, if you write
$$
u = \tan^{-1}(\dfrac{\cos{x}-\sin{x}}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}})
$$
then you can rewrite that as
$$
\tan u = \dfrac{\cos{x}-\sin{x}}{\cos{x}+\sin{x}}
$$
The stuff on the right simplifies to some exponential involving $x$; the stuff on the left similarly simplifies to something involving $u$. Set these equal, and see whether you can find a relationship between $u$ and $x$ as a result.

You'll notice I haven't done the work for you --- that's because you asked "what general steps can be taken," and I've answered that.

Comment: One more hint: at some point you're going to end up with $e^{ix}$ all over the place, and $e^{-ix}$ as well. If you use the letter $q$ for the first, then you can use $1/q$ for the second; you can do something similar with $e^{iu}$ (call it $r$, say). Then you end up with a polynomial relation between $q$ and $r$ which you can simplify before substituting back.